# Failing to properly configure an Apache2 sub-domain on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, domain-name-system

I've rented a small virtual private server that runs Ubuntu, and I'm trying to configure a sub-domain. Thanks to several resources I've figured out how I'm supposed to do this, but still it does not work at all.

Hopefully someone can help me find out what I've done wrong.

I've created a file called `<domain>.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. It contains the following:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

# Configuration for index.<domain> and <domain>.
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin administrator@<domain>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/<domain>/index

        ServerName index.<domain>
        ServerAlias <domain>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I've enabled the website using following command:

```
sudo a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/<domain>.conf
```

Furthermore I've configured the DNS settings as following:

```
Name            Type            Value         
<domain>        A               <ip-address>
index.|DOMAIN|  A               <ip-address>
```

Opening `http://<domain>` works perfectly fine but opening `http://index.<domain>` does not. Instead I get a message telling me that "This web page is not available".

---

`apache2ctl -S` returns the following:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

VirtualHost configuration:
    *:80 is a NameVirtualHost
        default server localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
    port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
    port 80 namevhost index.<domain> (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/<domain>.conf:4)
        alias <domain>
```

Comment: You need to figure out if it's a DNS or Apache problem first. Does `dig index.example.com` return the correct IP?

Comment: If you've confirmed that it's not a DNS issue, you should next check the log files that you've configured for the virtual host.

Comment: `apache2ctl -S` should show what apache's idea of the virtualhosts is.

Comment: @faker No it doesn't. The header contains a NXDOMAIN status and 0 answers, but I do not know what this means. This is what the authority section looks like:

`<domain>.  10800   IN      SOA     <nameserver>. hostmaster.<domain>. 2015022700 14400 3600 1209600 86400`

Comment: @wurtel I will add the result of that command in the above, please have a look.

Comment: `I do not know what this means` It means it has nothing to do with apache and you need to configure the dns records appropriately for `<domain>` so that the subdomain `index` exists.

Comment: It's really hard to help you here. DNS zone files have a very specific syntax. A trailing dot can change the meaning of the line completely. With your obscurification it's pretty much impossible to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: @faker Ok thank you, at least I now know where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

You set a subdomain named "www.domain" and you added a record for the subdomain "index.domain"

Try this:

In your vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin administrator@domain
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/domain/www

    ServerName domain
    ServerAlias www.domain

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And then run :

```
apache2ctl -t
service apache2 reload
```

In your zone file:

```
domain.     IN    A               W.X.Y.Z
www         IN    CNAME           domain.
```

And then run :

```
named-checkzone domain /path/to/zone/file/db.domain
service bind9 reload
```

Make sure your subdomain is resolved by your DNS server:

```
dig @W.X.Y.Z www.domain A +short
W.X.Y.Z
```